# How to calculate trigonometric function sin & cos in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i am using xalan java, i have to caluculate sin () and cos () in xslt. here is my example

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:math ="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
        extension-element-prefixes="math"> 
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match = "root/module[start-with(@name, phase)]">
            <xsl:variable name ="k" select ="0.0"=/>
            <xsl:variable name = "angle" select ="math:cos(k)"/>
            <theta x = "$angle">
            </theta>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: this is just example method which i tried and failed, can you please provide an example how to calculate trigonometric function in xslt. thank you

Comment: Well, use an XSLT processor like Saxon 9 (available on Maven or Sourceforge) which supports those functions instead of relying on Xalan which never got updated to support any developments in XSLT/XPath after version 1.0 from 1999. With Saxon 9 you get XSLT 2.0 and XPath 3.0 support and in the near future with Saxon 9.8 probably XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 support.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you provide me example for trigonometric function calculation in xslt

Comment: If you're using Xalan, you can use: http://exslt.org/math/functions/sin/index.html and http://exslt.org/math/functions/cos/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Saxon 9.6 or later and then e.g.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="math">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:sin(math:pi() div 2)"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

should work fine.

Comment: Xalan doesn't support trigonomatric function? thank you for example.

Comment: @Muddassir Xalan does support  trigonomatric functions as an extension (as I already told you more than 10 minutes ago).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: My error for example above is (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: for extension fuction, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.cos([ExpressionContext,]) i am stuck with this error

Comment: @Muddassir Read the documentation I pointed to. If you *really* get stuck edit your question and post your attempted code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks i got answer from documentation.